# WITH NOLOCK зло?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Там где я работаю  в хранимых процедурах в sql довольно активно используется конструкция `WITH(NOLOCK)`. Она используется для данных, которые могут очень часто запрашиваться и как мне сказали ее использование оправдано из-за соображений производительности. Насколько я знаю `WITH(NOLOCK)` - это аналог уровня изоляции `READ UNCOMMITTED` и означает отсутствие блокировок таблицы при выполнении запросов.

Однако на Хабре в статье "[7 вещей, которые разработчик должен знать о SQL Server](http://habrahabr.ru/post/170187/)" пишут, что во-первых `WITH(NOLOCK)` не гарантирует отсутствие блокировок, а во-вторых  цитирую:

> по поводу WITH NOLOCK. Поразило не то что будут блокировки, а то, что кто-то этой анафемой не только всерьез пользуется, но еще и рассчитывает, что при этом не будет блокировок

Вопрос: является ли злом использование `WITH(NOLOCK)`? Является ли это злом абсолютным или же нет? Когда его использование может быть оправдано?

Answer (score 6):

`WITH (NOLOCK)` не является абсолютным злом. Это просто хинт. Зло - это использование его не по назначению. Надо просто точно представлять себе все последствия его применения - чтения строк, которые никогда не станут строками, фантомные чтения, возможные дубликаты одного и того же значения при сканах - чтобы понять, что в живом приложении его использовать не стоит.

У `NOLOCK`/`READ UNCOMMITTED` есть одно явное предназначение - чтение невкомитанных данных. Мне, например, приходится им регулярно пользоваться при дебаге (в виде `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`), когда код остановлен в середине транзакции, и надо выяснить что с точки зрения кода сейчас происходит в базе.

Для всех остальных случаев, в которых раньше использовали `NOLOCK`/`READ UNCOMMITTED`, сейчас намного лучше подходит `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`.

P.S. А вот `SNAPSHOT` - это действительно зло!