# SQL Server 2012 - Когда использовать WITH(NOLOCK)?

Tags: sql-server

Документацию читал, но:

1. Когда следует использовать WITH (NOLOCK)?
2. Когда не следует использовать WITH (NOLOCK)?

Просьба отвечать своими словами, а не кидать ссылки столетней давности.

Comment: ссылка годовой давности - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/with-nolock-%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE, гарантирую что ответ еще актуален

Comment: Ответ не такой, какого жду я. Внимательно ознакомьтесь с моим вопросом, пожалуйста. Я до создания вопроса уже читал материал по ссылке.

Comment: Значит вам стоит уточнить - какого ответа вы ждете. по ссылке есть конкретный пример, (1) когда следует использовать `NOLOCK`. Во всех остальных случаях - не следуют. В целом - NOLOCK - это просто хинт, который отключает все блокировки, кроме schema stability. Если вам нужно их отключить, и вы понимаете все возможные последствия - используйте его. Если не нужно - не используйте :)

Comment: Хорошо. Объясните, пожалуйста ,что такое schema stability?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519(v=sql.105).aspx, раздел Schema Locks. Если хотите развернутого объяснения - задавайте отдельным вопросом :)

Comment: Я уже задал вопрос, который местные посчитали повтором.